# Open source wallets to host on our website

Tags: wallet

We are a team of experienced devs, also with experience and knowledge of Bitcoin, but with zero experience so far in Bitcoin/blockchain specific development.

We would like to host a Bitcoin wallet on our website and are exploring the development lift required from open source options. There will be frequent deposits/withdrawals, internal transactions and naturally security is of the highest priority.

Any advice on avenues to explore (and pitfalls to watch out for) as we assess options would be very helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: I've voted to keep this question open, because it is asking about an "actual problem with using Bitcoin", namely, how to accept payments on a website. I see some votes to close this question as a request for a service review or recommendation, but I digress: there is a difference between asking "How do I do XYZ?" and "What is the best XYZ service?".

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, the first answer that you received to this question is wholly inaccurate.

'Bitcoin Core' is a client (not a library or a wallet).

You're looking for something like 'BTCPayServer', which is a completely autonomous, self-hosted wallet solution that requires a server to spin and allows you to control every aspect of your interaction with the source code on a granular level with as much fine tuning as you desire.

Here's the site: https://btcpayserver.org/

There's a live demo for you to play with along with a wealth of documentation.

Comment: There is no other answer. I guess you are alluding to the [comment by @Prayank.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100587/open-source-wallets-to-host-on-our-website/100635#comment114020_100587)

Comment: Yes, apologies. Stackexchange won't let me add a comment to other comments until I hit the 50 point mark and this is still considered to be a "new" account.